# Do plant roots really "suffocate" due to lack of oxygen when over watered?

Tags: watering, roots, hydroponic

Should plant pots have drainage holes at the bottom is a [matter of intense debate](https://www.eplanters.com/blog/planters-with-drainage-holes-the-ultimate-guide/) among agriculturists and botanists across the world. While most acknowledge the importance of drainage holes, others question its efficacy, especially when compared to other alternative methods like terracotta pots and pebble layer at the bottom.

The primary argument of the "drainage holes are a must" camp is that the roots suffocate due to lack of oxygen in soil which is overly drained in water. But if that were the case, how can so many plants underwater (on the seas and ocean floors) be able to survive? Also, how come hydroponic systems work as the root is entirely submerged into the water in that case?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are mixing things up to come to a common conclusion. None of the points made are coherent as an argument.

- Underwater plants are adapted to live underwater.  Other plants would suffer from root rot.
- Orchids and other epiphytes have air-breathing roots.  I suspect they would drown underwater.
- Hydroponics provides a steady supply of circulated water, which has a steady stream of dissolved oxygen in it.  It is not the same as stagnant water which loses its oxygen.
- Different plants cope differently with different amounts of water.  Try planting a cactus in water-logged soil.

Clay pots with holes in them have worked in Asia for generations.  But it means that you have to water the plants regularly.  We grew up knowing (by accident) that without the holes, plants will die.

Comment: The last sentence is actually incorrect - plants in pots without holes don’t die (as proven multiple times), but need careful water management etc. because excess water doesn’t simply flow away.

Comment: @Stephie Indeed. There are various ways of water management like creating a pebble layer at bottom, moderate watering, using terracotta containers, etc. which experienced gardeners do anyway. A plant doesn't just die in pots without holes unless watered heavily or is out under heavy rains.